# How does this line of code allow [end=" "] to apply in between of the letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

So, I was studying basic things about Python. I encountered print function that basically prints something.

I learned that I could use `[end=""]` to end the print function. 
For example,

```
my_job = 'hacker'
print(my_job, end="")
```

Basically gives me,

```
hacker
```

Another example, using the same values as above,

```
print(my_job, end="test")
```

Basically gives me,

```
hackertest
```

However, I then saw a cool thread in this site about how does the `[end=""]` function really works. I then noticed @Ritesh Karwa post this code,

```
myjob = 'hacker'
for c in myjob: print(c, end=" ")
```

Basically gave him,

```
h a c k e r
```

I know that the space inside the "" in the `[end=]` allowed the output to have spaces, but just how did that work? I mean, removing the [for c in myjob:] and only using the print function, the output became,

```
hacker
```

What is the mechanism behind this `[for c in myjob:]` that allowed the `[end=]` to apply spaces in between of the letters, resulting into this output,

```
h a c k e r
```

I wanted to ask @Ritesh Karwa directly through comments, but I don't have enough reputation. I'm not confident that I asked my question clearly, but I did my best. Thank you in advance for the helpful answers. I'm also using Python 3.xx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, strings are also iterators (i.e. you can create a loop that will access them character by character). In this case:

```
for c in myjob:
```

is creating a loop where `c` will in turn have the value of each individual character in `myjob`.

If you then just did `print(c)` in the loop you would end up with

```
h
a
c
k
e
r
```

What the `end=' '` is doing is replacing the default `\n` (newline) character that would normally force each print statement to print on a separate line as above and instead  printing the contents of `end=' '` (i.e. a space) after each print. That's giving you

```
h a c k e r
```

One thing you often have to remember after using `end=` is that the next `print` (which may be completely unrelated) will resume directly after the previous print, so would appear on the same line. People often would use a separate `print()` to print a newline so the next, unrelated print statement starts on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

`myjob` is a string object, therefore an iterable. That means, that you can for example apply for loops such as `for letter in myjob` to iterate over all letters in the string.

As you have seen the optional end parameter of print replaces the standard end, which is a new line character with the one specified. So in this case, each occurrence in your for loop, the next letter is printed followed by a space. If you don't specify an end you will see that each letter would be printed to a new line.

Answer (score 0):

end=“” removes the invisible new line (\n) that gets added at the end of a printing action.
Useful for for loops if you don’t want to get your results on separate lines.